# mysql refusing to start on ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

[image]

I am trying to start MySQL but it is refusing , I have installed mysql but when i stoped it now it is refusing to start and even giving errors . The link to image shows error message . Any idea how to fix it ?

when i do a sudo service mysql status it gives an error shown in imgage with link .

I have tried to remove and reinstall same issue still .

Mysql process logs:

```
2022-04-20T07:08:08.550016Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) initializing of server in progress as process 13045
2022-04-20T07:08:08.570731Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-04-20T07:08:09.392163Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-04-20T07:08:11.456935Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

Comment: try this command `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Post here also the mysql process logs. And We can get an idea why is not starting...

Comment: @BhargavChudasama i tried that , it gives error of  ->  Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with an error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: try solution from this site https://serverfault.com/questions/981403/failed-to-start-mysql-community-server